# Truss rod and bow issue on electric guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-neck, truss-rod

So I have this guitar by Halo guitars, it's the Hellfire (might be called the Justifier now) but it's manufactured around 2007/8 and my uncle bought it at a thrift store a long time ago, all was fine just years later the strings broke and never was replaced then the floyd rose bridge came off then a pickup was pulled out (I have no idea how probably as a donor) and now present day it's been sitting for years and was gonna be thrown out but I like the design alot and wanna rebuild it, now it has everything but I tuned it and noticed that it's bowed so I tightened the truss rod and it kinda straightened but not fully and the string hight is like a whole centimeter. I don't wanna force it too much because the bolt you put the Allen (hex or torx) key on looks to have a lot of pressure of the back of the neck like the distance on the wood from the back and the part the truss rod touches looks really thin and I feel like tighten it too much will make it shatter. I'm I being too paranoid? I don't wanna just leave the guitar to dust on the wall and never be played bc it's really rare now not much on the internet and only 2 or on reverb for like nearly 2 grand so I wanna keep this one.
Pictures show dimensions and guitar

[[image: neckdimensions][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNk4D.jpg)

[[image: HaloHellfireguitar][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4W2H.jpg)

[[image: neckbow][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TPqh.jpg)

[[image: trussrod][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imp5K.jpg)

Comment: Consider taking it to a professional?

Comment: What is picture 3?  Is that the neck with a straightedge against the frets?  Are the strings still on the guitar in this picture?  If so, you're not too far from the right amount of relief.  But if not, you need to measure this with strings on.  Keep in mind that you are bending wood, so it's a good practice to let it settle in for a couple days after making a significant adjustment.  Also, you say the neck was initially bowed.  Bowed which way?  Concave toward the strings?

Comment: I think if you don't own feeler gauges or a depth gauge to actually measure the amount of relief, then you should take it to a professional. If the frets stick out of the sides of the fingerboard and scrape your hand when you play, then the fingerboard has dried out and shrunk, and it shrinks in both directions, so if the frets stick out then the fingerboard is too short and that pulls the neck into too much relief. If you don't know how to re-hydrate again that's a job for a pro.

Comment: If you must DIY then I suggest e-mailing them for advice: https://www.haloguitars.com/store/Guitar-Setup.html There's a chance that it's a double-action truss rod and the adjustment may be different from what you expect. Looks like these might be kind valuable so I wouldn't rush to fix it yourself unless you're sure you know what you're doing or you don't care about the value.

Comment: It would help to know what gauge strings you put on, and whether you tried adjustment with or without them on. And be absolutely certain the right Allen key is used - some Imperial are very close (but not close enough) leading to head damage, to the metric sizes. Also, please split the question into paragraphs - there are folk who won't bother reading one huge paragraph!

Comment: I don't really know if I can reply to individual comments because I don't be here much but 1. I tightened the truss rod and everything seems to be fine, 2. The 3rd picture the black rod is a arrow shaft that is perfectly straight to show the guitar necks curve (the straightest thing I have around) and 3. The bridge needs some replacement parts to put the strings back on to determine any more adjustments needed but that's gonna be a while because of other things I gotta take care of. The only thing now is that the neck is pretty straight but it's the backside wasn't sanded flat so looks bulged